# Angular JS $watch priority over ng-change

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am making a registration form using Angular JS where a function, `regisChange()`, is executed through `ng-change`.

I have another custom-made directive called `equals` that uses `$watch` to check the password fields and uses `ngModel.$setValidity('equals', password1==password2)` to set the validity of the form.

Ideally, whenever a user changes his password field, I would want the `equals` directive to be executed before `ng-change`. This is so that the `equals` can set the validity of the form before the `ng-change` refers to it.

The question is how do I execute a `$watch` on the change of input before the function in `ng-change`?

**HTML**

```
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="register-password1">Password</label>
    <input name="password1" type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password1" required ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="20" equals="{{user.password2}}" ng-blur="fieldValidate('password1')" ng-change="regisChange('password1')">
    <div class="error">{{error.password1}}</div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="register-password2">Confirm Password</label>
    <input name="password2" type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password2" required equals="{{user.password1}}" ng-blur="fieldValidate('password2')" ng-change="regisChange('password2')">
    <div class="error">{{error.password2}}</div>
  </div>
```

**Equals Directive**

```
welcome.directive('equals', [function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
    require: 'ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
      if(!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

      // watch own value and re-validate on change
      scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function() {
        validate();
      });

      // observe the other value and re-validate on change
      attrs.$observe('equals', function (val) {
        validate();
      });

      var validate = function() {
        // values
        var val1 = ngModel.$viewValue;
        var val2 = attrs.equals;

        // set validity
        console.log('val1: '+val1)
        console.log('val2: '+val2)
        ngModel.$setValidity('equals', val1 === val2);
      };
    }
  }
}]);
```

**regisChange() in the Controller**

```
$scope.regisChange = function(fieldName){
    console.log($scope.regisForm["password2"].$valid);
    if($scope.regisForm[fieldName].$valid){
      $scope.error[fieldName] = "";
    }
};
```

Comment: Do you have controller or other stuff, or only these 2 files?

Comment: @MaximShoustin hey, I added what the regisChange() does. Thanks for having a look at this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, if you have two watchers, D & C that both watch Z, it's best to be explicit about the dependency between D & C, so you don't end up with these ordering issues.

I'm not sure if its possible to guarantee the ordering of $watch and other data binding events. But there are a few things you could do.

1. Consolidate

   - Move your calculation of validity into your regisChange function, instead of using your custom directive. This will be easy in these simple cases where you're only checking a few values. This will eliminate the race condition between your equal directive's $watch handlers firing, and ng-change calling regisChange.
2. Be Consistent

   - You use $watch to check for equality, but then you rely on an event handler to clear an error. Why not $watch both password values and their $valid values (or just the whole input field) so that you can be sure you run your check whenever something changes.

In my mind, it makes sense that the ng-change fires first. It seems to most closely resemble an event handler which I would assume fires immediately after an event, whereas your $watch can only fire after the next $digest() cycle. That being said, it may never be clean to make ng-change and $watch play like how you want them to in this situation.

I'm not quite sure what the code is trying to in redisChange function anyway. If you could make a jsfiddle with all of the relevant bits, I could probably be more useful

Comment: Hey, thank you for the helpful answer. If you don't mind, I have a follow up question. How would I implement "$setValidity" of "ngModel" within the "regisChange" function instead of the directive? The only reason why I created another directive for this was for the $setValidity method that could change the $valid state of the form.

Comment: If you wrap your imports in a form and give everything a name, you can access the form and its inputs on $scope.

<form name="regis">
 <input name="password1"...
 <input name="password2"...
 ...

Will be accessible like $scope.regis.password1, and from there you can use $setValidity.

Personally, I dont have much experience w/ $setValidity, but it is indeed available if you put everything into a form. There probably more info on the angular API docs